# Scrollbars disappear from a <div> when using <br> tag

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, line-breaks

It seems really strange and I can't figure out why this is happening.

This is my code in CSS:

```html
<div style="width:580px; height:400px; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;">
 My content
</div>
```

I use a `div` to create a space of the given dimensions and add my content.

Everything works perfectly, until I force a line break with a `br` tag, then the scroll-bar disappear and, any content outside of the `div` area is lost (*or  inaccessible*).

Any comments why is this happening and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite weird. First of all, it would help if you could be more specific about where the issue is happening(browser, version, etc).

`overflow-x` and `overflow-y` are CSS 3 properties which may not be fully supported. See [THIS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp) for some details.

What I can tell you from experience is that the above properties have inconsistent behavior. So I would advise you to use `overflow:scroll`, which is supported in legacy mode and make sure whatever is inside that div will fit the width accordingly.

A second advice would be to stop using `<br />` tags, which are always a major pain. Instead use something like:

```
<div class="linebreak" style="width:100%;height:1em"></div>
```

or

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: Browser is GoogleChrome, version 22.0.1229.94 m. I havent tested any other browsers yet. Overflow:scroll; does the same thing (removes the scrollbars) when used with <br> tag although with your suggestion it works. No thoughts about what caused the problem in the first place though?

Comment: Yea I thought about this too but as I said overflow:auto; doesn't work either. Maybe its because its a server-based script providing the language and there is something wrong with it in the first place. Thanks for your answer. Accepted.